# How to add header in audio PCM data in node.js

Tags: node.js, audio, buffer, speech, pcm

How to add Wav header in RAW PCM format in node.js code

I have multiple RAW PCM buffers, so i am concating all buffers than i want to add wav/mp3/ogg  etc.. headre in PCM buffer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavefile to create a WAV file from PCM ... those other codec might need a diff package